# problema con django-videokit-0.0.4

Tags: django, djangorestframework

estoy tratando de usar django-videokit-0.0.4 para poder guardar videos en mis modelos sigo los pasos que me dan en la documentacion pero al final cuando corro el server me da este error:

```
 Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.        <locals>.wrapper at 0x04EFE8E8>
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django  \utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
  fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
  self.check(display_num_errors=True)
 File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django \core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
  include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
   File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
 File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\core\checks\model_checks.py", line 30, in check_all_models
errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 1283, in check
errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.3-py3.6.egg\django\db\models\base.py", line 1358, in _check_fields
errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
 File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django_videokit-0.0.4-py3.6.egg\videokit\models.py", line 43, in check
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django_videokit-0.0.4-py3.6.egg\videokit\models.py", line 51, in _check_video_utils_installed
 NameError: name 'checks' is not defined
```

por favor agradesco cualquier ayuda o comentario. El objetivo que deseo es poder guardar archivos tipo videos en uno de mis modelos como se haría utiliazando Imagenes si saben de otra forma para hacerlo diganmelo

Comment: Ya añadiste videokit a tus INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: si  e instale todo los requerimientos que tiene como Celery mediainfo y ffmpeg